# Type PriorityQueue is not generic in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, java-17

When creating a PriorityQueue I get `The type PriorityQueue is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>` .

```
import java.util.*;
public class PriorityQueue {
public static void main (String [] args) {

Queue<Double> queuePriority = new PriorityQueue<>();
        
        queue.offer(3.0);
        queue.offer(3.5);
        queue.offer(2.5);
        queue.offer(4.0);
        queue.offer(1.5);
        
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(queue.poll());
        }
    }
}
```

If I click "Remove type arguments", I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from PriorityQueue to Queue<Double>`.

Following recommended solutions in Eclipse lead to nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a naming conflict with Java's own PriorityQueue class and the compiler thinks you're instantiating your own class, not the built-in one. Just rename your class to something slightly different and it should be fine again.

Comment: Thank you, I though Eclipse would tell me not to name a class like that. Solved.

Comment: You can still name it anything you want including PriorityQueue except you'll just have to use the fully qualified name of the built-in class when instantiating so the compiler knows it needs to use that one, so your first line inside the main method would become:

`Queue<Double> queuePriority = new java.util.PriorityQueue<>();`

The compiler assumes you're referring to your class because local scope takes precedence over imported scope. Basically if the class is in the same package and has the same name, it will always use that. Best practice is to just use different naming though.